# GitHub Action workflow for running steps in parallel

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I am working on a project. I need to create a workflow to run integration tests on an iOS device.

Scenario:
**I've to run a local server at some port and in parallel I've run integration tests.**

Query:

1. Can I achieve this in Github Actions?
2. If yes then how?

I'll be thankful for the help.

Comment: For what I saw on the Github Community (source: https://github.community/t/steps-in-parallel/16343) you can't achieve it with GHA at this moment (it is only possible for jobs). But on the same thread people gave alternatives (without using directly GHA) via background tasks or GNU parallel.

Comment: You can check [Mocha Parallel Jobs on Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937238/mocha-parallel-jobs-on-github-actions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built in solution for parallel steps at the moment.

Workarounds:

- Run your server in the background (`server &`). Or as a daemon if it has it built in.
- If it's a container you can use `jobs.<job_id>.services`

  - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices

If you would like to have this feature you can try voting on this feedback thing: https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/14484

Comment: Are there any updates from GitHub weather they are planning to add this? Or is there a reason why not?

Comment: @LarsFlieger haven't seen any. I've added a link to GH feedback you can try.